# SQL Query DATEDIFF Based on Logic Addition Condition - How?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How would I write a query that counts how many days back in time it takes to add up to a cell value from another table?

For example, in the below two tables I want to start with the debit made by User A from TABLE 2 and count from TABLE 1 how many days backward in time (from the debit date) it takes User A to add up to the value in TABLE 2.

```
Date    User    Credits
Apr 30  A       25
Apr 30  B       75
May 1   A       25
May 2   A       25
May 2   B       75
May 3   A       50
May 3   B       75

Date    User    Debits
May 4   B       150
May 5   A       100
```

I want to start with each user's debit value from TABLE 2, and count how many days backwards (from the debit date) it takes to reach that amount of credits. In this case, the result I'm looking for User A is "5" - five days to reach 100. This needs to work for multiple users. The result for User B should be "3" - three days from May 4 back to May 2 to reach 150.

I'm flummoxed on how to begin. Is the solution a bunch of IF statements?

Sample Results:

```
 Debit Date User    Debit Amount    Days Back of Credits
 4-May      B       150             3
 5-May      A       100             5
```

Comment: But total of `A` in 3 days is adding up to 100. So why `5`? Also put sample data for more users in both table and what is the expected output for all users?

Comment: 5 is count back from the date of the debit, May 5.

Comment: What happens if table 1's date range extend past table 2's range?

Comment: It will and that's OK. I want to start with a selected debit, in this case 100 on May 5, and then count back from May 5 on the credits table as far back as it takes to add up to 100, from May 5 and earlier.

Comment: I am still not able to understand counting backwards logic. I would suggest to be more elaborate with some more sample data for some other users as well

Comment: can you post more sample data and the expected result ? Are you looking for a `SUM(table1) EQUAL table2` ? or just `>=` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your day diff is wrong but but two dates coming from table A is correct.

Verify with my result and also test with other sample date and let me know.

```
declare @TableA table(Dates date,Users varchar(50),Credits int)
insert into @TableA VALUES
('2017-Apr-30','A',25)
,('2017-Apr-30','B',75)
,('2017-May-1 ','A',25)
,('2017-May-2 ','A',25)
,('2017-May-2 ','B',75)
,('2017-May-3 ','A',50)
,('2017-May-3 ','B',75)


declare @TableB table(Dates date,Users varchar(50),Debit int)
insert into @TableB VALUES
('2017-May-4','B',150)
,('2017-May-5','A',100)

;with CTE as
(
select  A.Dates,A.Users
,(select sum(A1.Credits) from @TableA A1 
where a1.dates<=a.dates 
and a1.users=a.users)cr
from @TableA A
)
,CTE1 AS(
select b.Dates  [Debit Date],b.Users
,b.Debit [Debit Amount]
,(
select top 1 c.dates
from cte c where 
b.Users=c.users and c.cr>=b.Debit
)CreditDates
from @TableB B
)

select   [Debit Date],Users,[Debit Amount]
,datediff(day,CreditDates,[Debit Date])[Days Back of Credits]
,CreditDates -- just for test
from cte1
```

Comment: You rock - Thanks! All I had to change was flip a < to > and add an order by in CTE1. It works!

Answer (score 0):

try this.

the `cte` is to find the cummulative balance

```
; with cte as
(
    select  [User]      = t2.[User], 
            Debit_Date  = t2.[Date], 
            Debit_Amt   = t2.[Debits],
            Credit_Date = t1.[Date],
            Balance     = t2.[Debits] - SUM(t1.[Credits]) OVER (PARTITION BY t2.[Date] ORDER BY t1.[Date])
    from    table2 t2
            inner join table1 t1    on  t2.[User]   = t1.[User]
)
select  [User], 
        Debit_Date, 
        Debit_Amt, 
        [Days] = datediff(day, min(Credit_Date), Debit_Date) + 1
from    cte
where   Balance     >= 0
group by [User], Debit_Date, Debit_Amt
```

Comment: You rock too! This was very helpful. I think to make it work all I need to do is add a sub CTE to select the top 1 value I need. Very much appreciated! It won't let me score you yet because I have less than 15 reputation.